# How to map these entities in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following tables:

```
create table product (
id int primary key,
sku text unique,
descripcion text
);

create table price_list (
id int primary key,
name text not null
)

create table price_list_item (
id_price_list int,
id_product int,
price decimal(12,2)
)
```

And so i would like to map those tables to these classes:

```
public class PriceList {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private List<ProductPrice> prices;

 .....
}

public class ProductPrice {
  private int idProduct;
  private String sku;
  private String descripcion;
  private BigDecimal price
}
```

But i can't seem to find / understand how to do this using JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this code helps.

```
public class PriceList {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}

public class Product{
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(name="sku")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="descripcion")
    private String description;
}
```

prices is supposed to be returned by PriceListRepository which can implement JpaRepository. PriceList is the name of your entity class and Integer is the type of id. Similarly you can implement classes for other entities as well.

Comment: Thank you, what about the "PriceList" class having a list of "ProductPrices" objects?
Is there any way that JPA would insert into the intermediate table "price_list_item"?

Comment: I'd go about creating a stored procedure or an insert trigger on PriceList for doing the same. You can call Stored Procedures in JPA by using @Query annotation. If the code helped, your upvote and selecting it as answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @Harima555 If my post has answered your question, I'd appreciate if you accept it as the answer.